# segmentation fault because of character changement

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a board game [detailed information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi). I get segmentation fault just changing `problem_ch` from `' '`(space) to `'.'`. When I play by the moves and with `' '`, I don't get but when I play by the moves and with `'.'`I get.  I really and really don't understand what happening.

> Solved: Because of negative index, I get the segmentation fault. By
>   handling, It is solved.

Following moves:

```
3d
2d
5f
2e
1e
4b
4c
4a
3b
at 4b segmentation fault
```

Code:

```
void make_move(char board[][SIZE], size_t row, size_t col, char player)
{
    int rowdelta = 0;                     // Row increment
    int coldelta = 0;                     // Column increment
    size_t x = 0;                         // Row index for searching
    size_t y = 0;                         // Column index for searching

    // Identify opponent
    char opponent = (player == player_ch) ? computer_ch : player_ch;

    board[row][col] = player;             // Place the player counter

    // Check all squares around this square for opponents counter
    for(rowdelta = -1 ; rowdelta <= 1 ; ++rowdelta)
        for(coldelta = -1; coldelta <= 1; ++coldelta)
        {
            // Don’t check off the board, or the current square
            if((row == 0 && rowdelta == -1) || row + rowdelta >= SIZE ||
               (col == 0 && coldelta == -1) || col + coldelta >= SIZE ||
               (rowdelta == 0 && coldelta == 0))
                continue;

            // Now check the square
            if(board[row + rowdelta][col + coldelta] == opponent)
            { // Found opponent so search in same direction for player counter
                x = row + rowdelta;           // Move to opponent
                y = col + coldelta;           // square

                for(;;)
                {
                    x += rowdelta;              // Move to the
                    y += coldelta;              // next square


                    if(board[x][y] == problem_ch)      // If square is blank...
                        break;                    // ...give up

                    // If we find the player counter, go backward from here
                    // changing all the opponents counters to player
                    if(board[x][y] == player)
                    {
                        while(board[x -= rowdelta][y -= coldelta] == opponent) // Opponent?
                            board[x][y] = player;                                // Yes, change it

                        break;                      // We are done
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How about identifying the smallest subset of program producing SEG fault?

Comment: If you get a segmentation fault use a debugger, a minor problem: in `scanf(" %zd%c", &x, &y);`,  `size_t` wants `%zu` instead of `%zd`, and `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour

Comment: I reedit the post @rootkea

Comment: Hmm.  Just a guess: since `rowdelta` can be negative, can `board[row-rowdelta][col-coldelta]` evaluate to a negative index?  That’d cause a segfault, if you’re lucky.

Comment: @Alter Mann  I _think_ there is a C spec exception that allows `"%d"` with `unsigned`, `"%zd"` with `size_t`, etc. but can not find it.  Using this comment as a reminder to look for it.

Comment: yes you are right. But when I handle it, to limit boundries like if negative continue; but that time the game doesn't end as anticipated @Lorehead

Comment: @Alter Mann Found `fscanf()` detail: "`z` Specifies that a following `d, i, o, u, x, X, or n` conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `size_t` _or_ the corresponding signed integer type."  It is a language lawyer issue on how to treat "or".

Comment: @chux Isn't `%zd` the specifier for `ssize_t`?

Comment: @chux, oops, then gcc is raising a false warning: `format ‘%zd’ expects argument of type ‘signed size_t *’, but argument 2 has type ‘size_t *’`

Comment: Then you need to refactor.  I’m not saying that one language is better than the other for all purposes, but had you used STL array or vector, this would not have happened.

Comment: @Lorehead  `ssize_t` is not in the C spec.  Since it is not in the C spec, IMO, scan using `jd` into a `intmax_t` and the convert to `ssize_t`.

Comment: @chux Fine. `ptrdiff_t` from `<stddef.h>`, then.

Comment: @Alter Mann Agree that `"%zu"` is best vs `"%zd"` and correct.  Just not 100% confident that `"%zd"` is wrong.  I think the expectation I had in mind was on the `printf()` side anyways - so I'll stay with you on `"%zd"` with `scanf()` and `size_t *` as incorrect.

Comment: @Lorehead `ptrdiff_t` uses `"%td"` and not `"%zd"`.